# How can I insert multiple items of data into SQL using Web API?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, sql-insert

I have a code like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(CUSTOMER [] newCustomer)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (CUSTOMER item in newCustomer)
        {
            var AddedCust = db.CUSTOMERs.Add(item);
        }

        int insertedRecords = db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(insertedRecords);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

With Postman I am trying to post more than one record - but I get an exception:

```
{

    "NAME": "test1",
    "SURNAME": "Aleksandrova",
    "BIRTHPLACE": "Minsk",
    "GENDER": "F",
    "IDENTITYNO": "AA75 857445",
    "IDENTITYPINCODE": 2552,
    "BIRTHDATE": "1970-06-19T00:00:00"
}
{

    "NAME": "test2",
    "SURNAME": "Aleksat34t34ndrova",
    "BIRTHPLACE": "Minsk",
    "GENDER": "F",
    "IDENTITYNO": "AA75 857445",
    "IDENTITYPINCODE": 2552,
    "BIRTHDATE": "1970-06-19T00:00:00"
}
{

    "NAME": "test3",
    "SURNAME": "Aleksandrova",
    "BIRTHPLACE": "Minsk",
    "GENDER": "F",
    "IDENTITYNO": "AA75 857445",
    "IDENTITYPINCODE": 2552,
    "BIRTHDATE": "1970-06-19T00:00:00"
}
```

ERROR:

> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'First_API.Models.CUSTOMER[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please read [ask]. This error has been asked about - and answered hundreds of times already. What have you tried?

Comment: @CodeCaster I couldnt find the answer thats why I asked it

Answer (score 6):

Your json body is invalid, Json array should be enclosed in `[ ]` (square brackets) and each record should be separated by `,`(Comma)

Try to send api request with below json

```
[{

    "NAME": "test1",
    "SURNAME": "Aleksandrova",
    "BIRTHPLACE": "Minsk",
    "GENDER": "F",
    "IDENTITYNO": "AA75 857445",
    "IDENTITYPINCODE": 2552,
    "BIRTHDATE": "1970-06-19T00:00:00"
},
{

    "NAME": "test2",
    "SURNAME": "Aleksat34t34ndrova",
    "BIRTHPLACE": "Minsk",
    "GENDER": "F",
    "IDENTITYNO": "AA75 857445",
    "IDENTITYPINCODE": 2552,
    "BIRTHDATE": "1970-06-19T00:00:00"
},
{

    "NAME": "test3",
    "SURNAME": "Aleksandrova",
    "BIRTHPLACE": "Minsk",
    "GENDER": "F",
    "IDENTITYNO": "AA75 857445",
    "IDENTITYPINCODE": 2552,
    "BIRTHDATE": "1970-06-19T00:00:00"
}]
```

Comment: how can I return just data itself which was added?

Comment: I know. I get the number of inserted records for example with one record I write return ok(value) but this value is in the loop How can i return it?

Comment: @AlishSafarli, error which you posted is self explanatory, it it addressed before on stackoverflow that might be the reason for getting -1 on your question

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[
    {
        "NAME": "test1",
        "SURNAME": "Aleksandrova",
        "BIRTHPLACE": "Minsk",
        "GENDER": "F",
        "IDENTITYNO": "AA75 857445",
        "IDENTITYPINCODE": 2552,
        "BIRTHDATE": "1970-06-19T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "test2",
        "SURNAME": "Aleksat34t34ndrova",
        "BIRTHPLACE": "Minsk",
        "GENDER": "F",
        "IDENTITYNO": "AA75 857445",
        "IDENTITYPINCODE": 2552,
        "BIRTHDATE": "1970-06-19T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "test3",
        "SURNAME": "Aleksandrova",
        "BIRTHPLACE": "Minsk",
        "GENDER": "F",
        "IDENTITYNO": "AA75 857445",
        "IDENTITYPINCODE": 2552,
        "BIRTHDATE": "1970-06-19T00:00:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: You could add an explanation as to why you've formatted the JSON like you have, for completeness (see Prassad's answer).

Comment: "try" is not an answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster you can always do better